# Remove Asset from 3D scene, but not Library? (how to edit an asset?)

Tags: asset-browser

Re:  Blender 3.5

I pushed some assets from one Blender file (using [_bundle.blend](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/asset_browser.html#asset-bundles) method) to my new user library blend file.  When I opened my assets lib blend file, the assets were in the asset library as expected, but the 3D scene was empty, (also as expected).  I then wanted to edit one of these assets, so I dragged it into the 3D scene, whereupon it became an regular object, not an asset.  I made the edits and wanted to get it back into the asset library.  So I deleted the previous asset and marked the new one as an asset; however, when I then deleted the object (now marked as asset) from the 3D scene, it also is deleted in the asset library.  Now none of the other assets in the library (that were pushed in via _bundle) are in the 3D scene...so where are they?  In the outliner (under >Objects)...all the assets pushed via _bundle in the library are grayed out in the outliner except the one I dragged out and edited...so whats different about this one?   I find it odd from an asset management point of view that some assets (if they've been edited) must be in the 3D scene to exist in the asset library yet others don't.

I located the asset in the outliner under "Blender File > Current File > Objects" and made it a fake user, but deleting the object from the 3D scene still deletes it from the asset library.  The goal here is to have a library of assets that are "in the library" and not "in the 3D scene".  If they have to be in the scene, then they have to be arranged and spread out and if you had a bunch objects, that's extra steps.  If I want to edit an asset, I want to drag it out in to the 3D scene..make the edit and somehow "push" it back into the library, then delete it from the 3D scene to keep things clean, ...but I can't figure out how to do that.  Deleting the newly marked asset from the 3D scene deletes it from the library.

Here's another scenario.  Lets say I push 100 assets from one blend file (via _bundle) to my user library blend file.  Then I want to edit all 100 of those assets for whatever reason...do I have to drag them all out to the 3D workspace and edit them?...only to have to delete all the previous assets and "remark as asset" the edited ones?...and now leave the edited ones in the 3D scene lest I delete them and they get deleted from the library?  I'm fine if that's the case, I just want to understand why I have some assets that are not required to be in the 3D scene, while others seem to be.

Has anyone else observed this or aware of the issue / how to work around if so?